# How to use Android Shared Library (.so) in Linux PC by Java

Tags: java, linux, x86, apk, android-x86

I decompiled an APK file, and that app have native codes in a .so file.
Now I want to load that .so file in my java program in linux pc.
I want to use some function written in the native code.

Is there any way to use the Shared Lib (.so) in java program??